# To store the altered image as an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
final = decimal;
figure('Name','Final EMBEDED Image'),imshow(final);
[image path] = uiputfile({'*.jpg';'*.bmp';'*.tif'},'Save Encoded File As');
```

final is the altered image.
I have to store that image by giving the path and name of the image dynamically. for this i have tried uiputfile. the function is working but not serving the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`uiputfile` just returns the filename and path the user chooses, it doesn't save anything. You still have to save the image in some way:

```
fname = fullfile(path, image);
imwrite(final, fname);
```